# Level, depth of a directory from my computer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have two directory paths:
**Path 1** = "C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\"
**Path 2** = "C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\"
As you can see, **Path 1** is two levels deeper than **Path 2**
In other words **Path 1** depth is 6 and **Path 2** depth is 4
i need a function that can calculate this depth

**Edit :**
Here is another example for anyone who misunderstood my question

```
Path A :="c:\"  {This is level 1 or depth 1}  
Path B := "c:\foo"  {This is level 2 or depth 2}  
Path C := "c:\bar"  {This is level 2 or depth 2}  
Path D := "c:\foo\folder1"  {this is level 3 or depth 3}  
Path E := "c:\bar\folder2"  {this is level 3 or depth 3}
```

I think now its pretty clear that when i say **depth** i mean if i am in drive **C** how deep should i dive to get to the final folder
**Why do i need this ?**
Because in my program the user **sets a depth from the base directory** he has given and i have to search and find all the files that are in root of that base (if depth is 1) and if for example depth is 2 i must search inside any folder in the root too, and if it is 3 i will search for any files inside a folder that is inside another folder which that folder was at the root
the distance or depth difference that i needed was also needed for another feature in my program which can be calculated as

```
abs(depthFolder1 - depthFolder 2)
```

Comment: What's the expected distance between C:\foo and C:\bar? How about between C:\foo and D:\baz?

Comment: @RobKennedy Obviously "0"

Comment: "0" doesn't seem right, what about C:\foo and C:\foo?

Comment: Not obvious to me, although it is indeed what your function would return. What about the distance between C:\foo\quux and C:\bar? Thinking of this as a tree, I'd say the distance was 3. (Draw the nodes, and then count the edges you traverse from one leaf to the other.) I'd say the distance from C:\ to D:\ is undefined because there's no root node for the trees. Sertac's example is the one that's *obviously* zero.

Comment: @RobKennedy, there **is** a root note between C:\ and D:\ , namely `MyComputer`. It just depends...

Comment: Yes, indeed, it depends: do you use real directories or (real or virtual) folders in the file system. Since then, e.g. zip files and the control panel are items in that system too.

Comment: honestly i just realized my question was quite ambiguous, mainly because i didn't consider the Tree side of this question, which points that c:\foo and c:\bar distance is not 0, which i understand, but i don't need such a distance and if my question suggested i need, i apologize

Comment: For your application I wouldn't bother with this. You just need to limit the search to the specified level. To do this I would just add the level to the search function and when the search function finds a directory recursively call the search function with the new path and the level reduced by 1 (unless the level is zero when you ignore the subdirectories).

Answer (score 0):

Get the difference between the two paths and count the number of `\`.

**Untested, because don't have Delphi open**

```
uses Math;

function GetSamePart(const A,B: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
  MinLen: integer;
begin
  i:= 0;
  MinLen:= Min(Length(A), Length(B));
  while i < MinLen do begin
    if lowercase(A[i+1]) = Lowercase(B[i+1]) then inc(i)
    else break;
  end; {while}
  if i = 0 then Result:= ''
  else Result:= Copy(A, 1, i);
end;

function OccurrencesOfChar(const S: string; const C: char): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    if S[i] = C then
      inc(result);
end;

function CountPaths(const Pathname: string; PathChar: char = '\'): integer;
begin
  if PathName = '' then Exit(0);
  Result:= OccurrencesOfChar(PathName, PathChar);
  if PathName[Length(PathName)] <> PathChar then Inc(Result);
end;

function GetPathDistance(const A,B: string): integer;
var
  ADiff, BDiff: string;
  FirstDiff: integer;
begin
  FirstDiff:= Length(GetSamePart(A,B));
  if FirstDiff < Length(A) then ADiff:= Copy(A, FirstDiff+1, Length(A)-FirstDiff);
  if FirstDiff < Length(B) then BDiff:= Copy(B, FirstDiff+1, Length(B)-FirstDiff);
  Result:= CountPaths(ADiff) + CountPaths(BDiff);
end;
```

Comment: looks case-sensitive :-P

Comment: Yes, it's the alpha pre-release of my ultimate path distance counting library.

Answer (score 0):

```
const 
  Path1 = "C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\";
  Path2 = "C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\";

var 
  sl1, sl2: iJclStringList;

procedure Init(out sl: iJclStringList; const CanonicalPath: string);
begin
  sl := JclStringList();
  sl.Split( AnsiUpperCase( CanonicalPath ), '\' );
  if sl.Count <= 0 then exit;
  if sl.Last = '' then sl.Delete( sl.LastIndex );
end;

var i: integer;

begin
  Init( sl1, Path1 );
  Init( sl2, Path2 );

  i := 0;
  while (i < sl1.Count) and (i < sl2.Count)
    and (sl1[i] = sl2[i]) 
  do
      Inc(i);

  // now i maps to the first different element
  Difference := Max(sl1.Count, sl2.Count) - i;

  sl1 := nil;
  sl2 := nil;
end;
```

http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/Category:IJclStringList_Methods

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetDirLevel(aDirectory: string): integer;
var
  a_Index: integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  aDirectory := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(aDirectory);
  for a_Index := 1 to Length(aDirectory) do
    if IsPathDelimiter(aDirectory, a_Index) then
      inc(Result);
end;

function GetComparedLevel(aBase, aDirectory: string): integer;
begin
  aBase := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(aBase);
  aDirectory := ExtractRelativePath(aBase, aDirectory);
  if POS('..', aDirectory) = 1 then
    Result := -1
  else
    Result := GetDirLevel(aDirectory);
end;
```

This uses RelativePath to the base to determine level.  So if your directory is not in the BaseDir it will return -1.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(GetComparedLevel('c:\temp', 'c:\temp\level2\level3\level4'));//will return 3
  Label2.Caption := IntToStr(GetComparedLevel('c:\temp\level', 'c:\temp\level2\level3\level4'));//will return -1

end;
```

Answer (score -2):

First of i appreciate all other answers
But before others posted their answer i already had found mine

```
function findPathDepth(path: String): integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  depthCounter: Integer;
begin
  depthCounter := 0;
  // path.Length - 2 in case there is an extra "\" at the end
  for I := 0 to path.Length - 2 do
    if (path[i] = '\') then
      inc(depthCounter);

  Result := depthCounter;
end;

function findPathDepthDistance(path1: String; path2: String): integer;
begin
  if (ExtractFileDrive(path1) = ExtractFileDrive(path2)) then
      Result := abs(findPathDepth(path1) - findPathDepth(path2));
  else 
      Result := -1;
end;
```

Once again thanks.

Comment: Your code thinks the distance between "C:\foo\bar\" and, "C:\bar\" is 1.

Comment: @Sertac: indeed. I actually wonder what he considers the depth between two unrelated directories.

Comment: He's said it's zero, @Rudy, "obviously."

Comment: @SertacAkyuz well i want it to return 1, for my purpose that 1 is the right answer, in my book if c:\ is level 1, any other folder inside is level 2, and if there is another folder inside any of those folder, all of them are level 3, that is what i need to know, and that is what my function returns, if anyone else needs something else they can change it to their needs.

Comment: You really should delete this entire question because it's not going to be useful to anybody. You should think harder before asking.